# jQuery show() animations or effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects, show

I have some javascript hiding and showing some rows in my table every 2 seconds for example. But I want some effects or animations in jquery for: show(). I tried slideDown('slow') but it doesn't animate, not sure why? fadeIn('slow') works fine though but not slide?

My JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var max = 0;
var index = 0;

$(function() {

    max = $("tbody tr.hidden").length;
    ticker();
});

function ticker() {
    $("tbody tr.hidden:visible").hide();

    var a = index;
    var b = index + 1;
    var c = index + 2;
    $("tbody tr.hidden:hidden").filter(":eq(" + a + "), :eq(" + b + "), :eq(" + c + ")").show(1000); /* WANT TO ANIMATE THIS */

    index += 3;
    if (index>= max) index = 0;    

    setTimeout("ticker()", 2000);
     $('tbody tr:visible:even').css('background-color', '#114c00');
}

</script>
```

My HTML

```
<table id="gradient-style" summary="Currency">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="flag"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="currency"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="title"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="buy">We Buy</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sell">We Sell</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Logo Goes here?</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="fixed">
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/USD.png" /></td>
            <td >USD</td>
            <td>US DOLLAR</td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="fixed">
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/EUR.png" /></td>
            <td>EUR</td>
            <td>EURO</td>
            <td class="value"><span>5.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
            </div>
        <tr id="fixed">
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/JPY.png" /></td>
            <td>JPY</td>
            <td>JAPANESE YEN</td>
            <td class="value"><span>8.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>

        </tr>

        <tr class="hidden">
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/CAD.png" /> </td>
            <td>CAD</td>
            <td>TEST1 DOLLAR</td>
            <td class="value"><span>8.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
        </tr>

       <tr class="hidden">
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/CNY.png" /> </td>
            <td>CNY</td>
            <td>TEST2 YUAN</td>
            <td class="value"><span>8.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/USD.png" /> </td>
            <td>CAD</td>
            <td>TEST3 DOLLAR</td>
            <td class="value"><span>8.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
        </tr>

         <tr class="hidden">
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/CAD.png" /> </td>
            <td>CAD</td>
            <td>TEST4 DOLLAR</td>
            <td class="value"><span>8.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
        </tr>

       <tr class="hidden" >
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/CNY.png" /> </td>
            <td>CNY</td>
            <td>TEST5 YUAN</td>
            <td class="value"><span>8.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td class="flags"><img src="flags/USD.png" /> </td>
            <td>CAD</td>
            <td>TEST6 DOLLAR</td>
            <td class="value"><span>8.10</span></td>
            <td class="value"><span>3.1</span></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) shows that you can use 'slow' 'fast' or numbers as a parameter for most (if not all) time values. The "show" and "slideDown" methods work mostly the same.

So maybe your selector actually doesn't return anything?

try:

```
var selector = $("tbody tr.hidden:hidden").filter(":eq(" + a + "), :eq(" + b + "), :eq(" + c + ")");
alert(sizeof(selector));
```

to make sure you are selecting some elements

EDIT:

try this

```
$.each($("tbody tr.hidden:hidden").filter(":eq(" + a + "), :eq(" + b + "), :eq(" + c + ")"),function(i,val){
            $(this).show(750);
        });
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't actually do anything?

Comment: did it popup at least? If it didn't I'm guessing your code doesn't even get thr. If it did and it's 0 you have to change your selector

Comment: Nothing popped up, tried a simple alert('hello'); and it works, so the code is fine? Answer above says not possible to have effects on tr elements

Comment: My answer is not relevant if the selector can't find the element. It might be once that is sorted out, but The_Butcher's answer should be OK with a TR.

Comment: Oh i see, I will have to sort the selector out .. any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this: (Just tried it but didnt work)

.show( function animation(){
$(this).slideDown('slow');
}

Comment: if nothing popped up it means the code didn't even get there. Thus your animation is not firing? You can just use .slideDown('slow') as the slide functions already .show() and .hide() automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that won't work with a tr. Try doing the same thing, only with the td and th elements in the row.

Comment: i think you're onto something :)

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `setTimeout("ticker()", 2000);` with `setInterval("ticker()", 2000);`

Comment: This actually does something, however it acts funny sliding down all the elements 3 at a time, I believe something to do with index values.

Also it stops animating after a while

Comment: May be i can help , if i get to see the entire code for the problem

Comment: Ok thanks, I just added my HTML - essentially top 3 rows are fixed, and the next 6 rows(hidden) fadeIn 3 at a time. Thanks.